# How to I find files in the csproj which are missing from the file system?

Tags: csproj

During a spike sprint to experiment moving to .net core I've accidentally deleted files without removing them from our legacy csproj file.

Is there an easy way to find files that are in the csproj file but missing from the file system.

Answer (score 0):

Posting my own answer here, as most searches uncover people trying to find files that are on the file system but missing in the csproj.

There is a very handy Visual Studio extension that will do this: [Show Missing Files](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/900b48cc-52b5-4afa-b4db-f1c3655c32aa)